# Add row to one table but not the other with v-for in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, json, for-loop, vue.js

I need to add rows in table `#dynamic` but table `static` shouldn't be affected.

If I click the button with the code below, both tables will be updated, because they have the same `v-for`. And, if I put a `v-for` in a `v-for` my data won't be fetched. I can't figure out how to "unique" the first table.

#### vue/html:

```
<template>
  <table id="dynamic">
    <tr v-for="rows in list">
      <td>Content of row {{ rows.item1 }}</td>
      <td>Content of row {{ rows.item2 }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div @click="block = !block">click</div>

  <table id="static">
    <tr v-for="rows in list">
      <td>Content of row: {{ rows.item3 }}</td>
      <td>Content of row: {{ rows.item4 }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

### js

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      list: [],
    };
  },
  props: ['channelId'],

  mounted() { },
  created() {
    this.fetchChannel(this.channelId);
  },
  methods: {
    fetchChannel: function (channelId) {
      $.getJSON('/api/channel/' + channelId, function (data) {
        this.list = data;
      }.bind(this));
    },
  }
}
```

I found some examples for help like [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jjelic/pen/yevNLZ) or [fiddle](https://codepen.io/jjelic/pen/yevNLZ) but I am not successful with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `#static` table is truly never meant to update when the its data changes, this would be a case for using [the `v-once` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once):

```
<table id="static" v-once>
  <tr v-for="rows in list">
    <td>Content of row: {{ rows.item3 }}</td>
    <td>Content of row: {{ rows.item4 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This will tell Vue to render the table only once and then ignore it upon any re-renders.

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2v250xvo/1)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Cheers